# Align row items across column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a table for displaying content of varying sizes along with a description with Jetpack Compose. So the layout is

```
Column {
    Row {
        WhateverContent()
        Text()
    }
    ...
}
```

Because the content has varying sizes, I'd like to right-align them inside each (first) row item according to the widest element. So essentially align the start of each text field. However, I can't find the right combination of modifiers to achieve this. I can:

- Right-align the column items to get rid of excess space at the left of each icon, but this leaves the text unaligned.
- Arrange row items, but this is only for the whole row - not individual items
- Put weighted spacers at the beginning of each row. This is my best attempt, but because the text is split into multiple lines, the starts of the texts are still not aligned.
- Wrap the text in a Surface with `fillMaxWidth`, but the fill varies with the size of the content and produces differently sized containers.

Here's also an example visualisation with some guides and spacing in red. The long line depicts the alignment line, and boxes are varying spacing.

[image: example]

What could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A suboptimal way of doing it is to weight the row items explicitly and to use an inner row for aligning the variable-size content.

```kotlin
Column {
    Row {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.2f)) {
            Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
            WhateverContent()
        }
        Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.8f))
    }
}
```

This has the drawback of forcing the ratio though, so newly added wide elements could overflow or there could be way too much space. But at least the alignments are solid.